# Convergence in distribution of sums of Bernoulli variables

Tags: convergence-divergence, random-variables, central-limit-theorem

Let $A_{j,n}$ and $B_{j,n}$ be two triangular arrays of independent Bernoulli variables such that

$$
\begin{array}{l}
\mathbb{P}\left[A_{j,n}=1\right] = p_{A,n},~~\mathbb{P}\left[A_{j,n}=0\right] = 1-p_{A,n},\\
\mathbb{P}\left[B_{j,n}=1\right] = p_{B,n},~~\mathbb{P}\left[B_{j,n}=0\right] = 1-p_{A,n}.
\end{array}
$$

Besides when $n\rightarrow\infty$ we have $p_{A,n}\rightarrow p_A\in(0,1)$ and $p_{B,n}\rightarrow p_B\in(0,1)$. Let know $\Gamma_n$, $\gamma_{A,n}$ and $\gamma_{B,n}$ be the random variables defined as

$$
\begin{array}{l}
\Gamma_n = \frac{1}{n}\,\sum_{j=1}^nA_{j,n}\cdot B_{j,n},\\
\gamma_{A,n} = \frac{1}{n}\,\sum_{j=1}^nA_{j,n},\\
\gamma_{B,n} = \frac{1}{n}\,\sum_{j=1}^nB_{j,n}.
\end{array}
$$

Obviously the product $A_{j,n}\cdot B_{j,n}$ is still a triangular array of Bernoulli variables, with new probability of begin $1$ or $0$. Define now

$$
\Phi_n = \frac{\Gamma_n-\gamma_{A,n}\cdot \gamma_{B,n}}{1+\Gamma_n-\gamma_{A,n}-\gamma_{B,n}}.
$$

I need to find the asymptotic distribution of $\Phi_n$ when $n\rightarrow\infty$.

For the variable $\Gamma_n$, $\gamma_{A,n}$ and $\gamma_{B,n}$ alone I can use a standard CTL theorem, since they are the average of iid variables. Nevertheless I can't still find the distribution of $\Phi_n$ since it involves a non-trivial combination of the variables. I am pretty convinced that the continuous mapping theorem should be somehow invoked.

Comment: I think I have found the solution. Both numerator and denominator are asymptotically gaussian. The ratio of two N(0,1) variables is Cauchy distributed, nevertheless in my case the denominator has non-null mean, so we must use the result in this paper of Hinkley:
http://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2334671.pdf?acceptTC=true
In particular it occurs that the standard deviation of the denominator is much smaller than the mean of the denominator, whence the gaussian approximation in equation (5) of the paper by Hinkley applies.